# Page fade-out when navigating between pages only works sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get pages to do a quick fade to black then fade in when navigating within the site. The below code is located right after the opening body tag.

I've tried a few tutorials and some solutions suggested on SO and this is the closest I've come so far:

```js
$('body').css('display','none');
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $('body').fadeIn();
          $('a').on('click', function(event) {
          var theTarget = this.getAttribute('target')
          if (theTarget != "_blank") {
             var thehref = this.getAttribute('href')
      event.preventDefault();
      $('body').fadeOut(function() {
         window.location = thehref
         alert(href)
      });
           }
          });
       });
       setTimeout(function() {
          $('body').fadeIn();
       },1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

An alert box pops up with the href that was just clicked and the page fades out how I would expect. *But* when I comment out the alert the page doesn't fade out at all and just navigates as normal to the page clicked.

This made me wonder if the `.preventDefault()` method wasn't being invoked properly or at the right time but trial and error has proven unfruitful.

Comment: You must try to follow good coding principles. Some of your statements ends with ; and others are just left open. Can you end your statements correctly and try it out and see if it doesn't work? I don't see anything specifically wrong with your approach.

Comment: Please check the answer below to your problem.